# Compile assets for multiple modules with vite

Tags: laravel, vite

I am building a website using laravel. Website has many modules, each module has its own js and scss. I want to compile all js, scss of all modules every time I type 'npm run build'.

Below is my code.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import glob from 'glob';

const modules = ['Admin', 'Blog'];

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: modules.map((module) => {
        const inputFiles = [
            ...glob.sync('./Modules/${module}/Resources/assets/js/*.js'),
            ...glob.sync('./Modules/${module}/Resources/assets/sass/*.scss'),
        ];
        
        return laravel({
            input: inputFiles,
            publicDirectory: 'public/build/',
            buildDirectory: module,
            refresh: true,
        });
    }),
});
```

The above code only builds the Admin module but ignores the Blog, please tell me where it went wrong. Thanks a lot.